# Customise Azure bot framework in NodeJs using DirectLine JS

Tags: node.js, azure, direct-line-botframework, azure-bot-service

I am looking for a solution which has Customised Azure bot in website. I am not looking for an iFrame integration, As i have already explored. I need a solution which gives me an option to make UI changes in the bot window and invoke Live agent Chat window(Third party) from the existing Chatbot.
I tried these link below which dint help

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

Comment: Please explain what you mean by didnt help?

Comment: The  link you provided contains some tips on integrating the Bot Framework UI into your React or non-React website. I suggest you check [https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#advanced-web-chat] for Information on Advanced Web Chat,Direct Line and DirectLineJS integration

Answer (score 1):

I understand exactly what you need.
It's true that the github url you pasted won't help but I know you'll get a lot of tips from the Direct Line and DirectLineJS documentation from the Advanced part.
You simply need a way to integrate to the Bot Framework from your existing UI system and hence using the Bot as just an Endpoint.

Your solution lies in the actual implementation methods for various channels that is supported by Bot Framework. Take Skype or Facebook for instance.

You need to study and configure WebHooks, Direct-Line Channels.

First: Use the Azure Portal to add a new website to your Bot in Channel property.
Secret Keys would be generated for you after then you can configure for version 1.1 or 3.0. 
Check the Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-concepts

Now your site can be configured to talk to the Bot Framework via Web Clients and Sockets as API requests.

With these, you have the priviledge to use your own UI with the Bot Framework.